# Retrieve Jar BLOB - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jar, blob

I have a table in SQL Server where a jar file is stored as a BLOB file. I want retrieve the jar out of the BLOB.

I am using the below query but not sure what to put instead of `xml` to get the jar:

```
select CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),jar_blob))) from CUSTOM_LIB where ID = '1';
```

Or is it retrievable at all using SQL query?

Comment: Is the `jar_blob` column data type `varbinary(MAX)`? In that case, simply `SELECT jar_blob  FROM CUSTOM_LIB WHERE ID = '1';`

Comment: jar_blob is of type varbinary of length '-1'.

Comment: `SELECT jar_blob FROM CUSTOM_LIB WHERE ID = '1';` is giving only the particular column with data like '0xADBB...'

Comment: The returned binary value is the entire jar file stored in the blob column.

Comment: My question is how do I get it as a .jar file not as a binary file.

Comment: Do you mean how to save the column contents to a file with a jar extension?

Comment: Yes Dan, that's what I need.

Comment: Exporting the value to a file is a simple task in most programming and scripting languages. I can post a PowerShell example if that will help. Creating files using T-SQL is a hack that should be avoided.

Comment: It will be of great help